# Determine which are the successful transaction using BlockChain API

Tags: blockchain.info

From this BlockChain API
http://blockchain.info/address/1AJbsFZ64EpEfS5UAjAfcUG8pH8Jn3rn1F?format=json

Are those considered as successful transaction?
If not, I would like to know which are successful inputs(receivables) for that sample address.

thanks!